# focus on a user control inside an aspx page after clicking a button inside the user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control inside an aspx page, after the aspx page loads, when I click some button inside that user control, I want the focus to come back to user control after that  button click action is complete and the aspx page loads again.

Comment: What about focusing using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event in your user control that will allow the .aspx page to subscribe to that event so that it can set focus to the element in the user control after the form posts back, like this:

```
public class UserControlClass
{
    // Define event that will be raised by user control to anyone interested in handling the event
    public event UC_Button1ClickEventHandler UC_Button1Click;
    public delegate void UC_Button1ClickEventHandler();

    // Mechanism to allow event to be raised by user control
    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UC_Button1Click != null) 
        {
            UC_Button1Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your .aspx page, you need to subscribe to the event in the user control and say what method will actually handle the event, like this:

```
userControl1.UC_Button1Click += Button1_Click;
```

Finally, the click event handler needs to exist, like this:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Set focus here to user control element, text box for example
    ((TextBox)userControl.FindControl("TextBox1")).Focus();
}
```